# Absolute difference between consecutive array elements

Tags: c, arrays

Is there any simple way to find the absolute difference between consecutive array elements?

Comment: What do you mean by "absolute" difference? Could you give an example?

Comment: Do you want to find difference between all pairs of consecutive elements in an array?

Comment: array of 4 elements 1 4 6 3  absolute difference |1-4|=3 |4-6|=2 |6-3|=3

Comment: Did you write any code for this?

Comment: Well, subtracting them seems like a plan, no?  If the result it negative, change its sign?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op didn't show any attempt or documentation on solving his problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assuming that you have an array like `arr[n]`:

You can define another array to keep differences like `diff[n-1]` and then you just need a loop like:

```
for(i=0; i<n-1; i++) {

   diff[i] = abs(arr[i]-arr[i+1]);  
}
```

Don't forget to include `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score -1):

```
    process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('ascii');
var inputString="";
var currentLine=0;
process.stdin.on('data',function(data){
    inputString+=data;
      inputString=inputString.split('\n');
      main(inputString);
});
function main(str){
        var dat=str[0].split(' ',2).map(el=>Number(el));
       var arr=str[1].split(' ').map(el=>Number(el));
        console.log(arr);
      var constant=dat[1];
      var newArr=[];
      let diff=0;
       for(let i=1;i<=arr.length;i++)
       {
            diff=Math.abs(arr[i-1]-arr[i]);
            if(diff==constant)newArr[i-1]=0;
            if(diff>constant)newArr[i-1]=1;
            else if(diff<=constant)newArr[i-1]=0;

       }

       console.log(newArr.join(' '))


}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Unfortunately your answer appears incomplete, poorly formatted, and not written in C.